# Replace missing values with the mean of surroundings values

Tags: r, time-series, na, zoo

My dataset looks like the following (let's call it "a"):

```
date value
2013-01-01 12.2
2013-01-02 NA
2013-01-03 NA
2013-01-04 16.8
2013-01-05 10.1
2013-01-06 NA
2013-01-07 12.0
```

I would like to replace the `NA` by the mean of the closest surroundings values (the previous and the next values in the series).

I tried the following but I am not convinced by the output...

```
miss.val = which(is.na(a$value))
library(zoo)
z = zoo(a$value, a$date)
z.corr = na.approx(z)
z.corr[(miss.val - 1):(miss.val + 1), ]
```

Comment: have you thought about Imputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `na.locf` (Last Observation Carried Forward) from package `zoo`:

```
R> library("zoo")
R> x <- c(12.2, NA, NA, 16.8, 10.1, NA, 12.0)
R> (na.locf(x) + rev(na.locf(rev(x))))/2
[1] 12.20 14.50 14.50 16.80 10.10 11.05 12.00
```

(does not work if first or last element of `x` is `NA`)

Comment: OK, but I want to change NA's by these values inside the "a" dataset.

Comment: @user2165907 All you have to do is take his final line and redirect it back, i.e. `x <- (na.locf(x) + rev(na.locf(rev(x))))/2`

Comment: a$value <- (na.locf(x) + rev(na.locf(rev(x))))/2

Comment: @rcs I was wondering if the last neighbor value of NA is not numeric, I mean, it a character kind of like  NAs, or outliers, how to change the code to find the mean of surroundings values then?

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly this in 1 line of code with the Moving Average **na.ma** function of the **imputeTS** package

```
library(imputeTS)
na_ma(yourData, k = 1)
```

This replaces the missing values with the mean of the closest surroundings values.
You can even additionally set parameters.

```
na_ma(yourData, k =2, weighting = "simple")
```

In this case the algorithm would take the next 2 values in each direction. You can also choose different weighting of the values(you might want that values closer have more influence)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this package!